# pipenv run error "The system cannot find the path specified"

Tags: pipenv

I am running command pipenv run "python shotty/shotty.py" in my windows PowerShell. In return I am getting this error "The system cannot find the path specified". I do have folder shotty(in my current directory) and a file shotty.py within it.

Comment: Show the complete stacktrace and the code producing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try `python ./shotty/shotty.py`

./ stands for the current directory

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes.

```
pipenv run python shotty/shotty.py
```

With quotes, Powershell treats `python shotty/shotty.py` as one single argument, and tries to find a directory named `python shotty`, and a file named `shotty.py` in it. The arguments can be grouped correctly *without* quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I wasn't using quotes in the command.  I discovered it was because I had an apostrophe in my project's folder name.  I renamed the folder without the apostrophe and recreated the pipenv for the new folder name and `pipenv run` works now.